# Trouble Setting up Open SSH with Putty

Tags: server, ssh, 10.10, security, putty

I for the life of me can't seem to get openSSH to work on Ubuntu Server 10.10 with keys I generated in PuttyGen on my Windows machine. After hours of trial and error and web searches I can't get my ssh service to accept my private key!

Here is my [sshd_config](http://pastebin.com/u8qZFgUw).

I generated my public and private keys using Putty in Windows then used a ssh connection to paste my key from putty directly into my authorized_keys2 file located in */etc/ssh/publickeys/authorized_keys2*

The authorized_keys2 file looks something like: `ssh-rsa  AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAA...` with no email or anything at the end of it. I just pasted it straight from PuttyGen without using a key comment.

I feel like it's not working because of some nuance I am not understanding or some unusual setting or incompatibility. I've restarted the ssh service (and the machine) to no avail.

What are some common pitfalls I might have gotten myself into? Is there a simpler way to generate ssh keys that putty can use in windows?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it. My problem was that I needed to convert the public key to OpenSSH's format. This required the use of the following command: `ssh-keygen -i -f puttygen_key > openssh_key` which converted my putty generated key into an openssh key which I then simply renamed to authorized_keys and boom it works.

Comment: Thanks. Should have known that option in ``ssh-keygen`` before!

Answer (score 0):

You must write the content of your `name_of_key.pub` into your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file and that's it the workaround is similar to:

1. Install openSSH (done as you point)
2. Generate an rsa in the client machine to share.
3. Copy the content of the `name_of_key.pub` into the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` in the server.
4. Enjoy fully authorized communication with the server from the client machine.

More on creating sshkeys with PuTTYgen [here](http://theillustratednetwork.mvps.org/Ssh/Private-publicKey.html) and [there](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter8.html) (note that you just need to change the step when you copy the text to the server, now the server is **linux!**)

You also can use google's [Secure Shell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo), [here](http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromiumos/platform/assets.git;a=blob;f=chromeapps/hterm/doc/faq.txt) you can find how to share a key-pair using it.

Comment: Does the known_hosts file need to be one line? Puttygen creates a multi-line file for the .pub key. Also, is this file required to be in ~/.ssh/known_hosts because my authorized_keys file is in /etc/ssh/publickeys